# How can drag and drop c# object from desktop app to web page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a desktop app and I want to copy c# object from desktop to html. I don't want to serialize object because desktop app use this method same time.

It's work but I don't want this

```
 CustomObject object = new CustomObject (1,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now);
 string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
 DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.Copy);
 Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

I want this

```
 CustomObject object = new CustomObject (1,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now);
 DoDragDrop(object , DragDropEffects.Copy);
 Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: `It's work but I don't want this` Why don't you want this?

Comment: Because it's used lots of method I don't want to change this methods for this operation